# Breeze with Node and Mongodb - getting a working Zza sample on Debian?

Tags: node.js, express, breeze

I can't get a version of the Breeze Zza sample application to work (with Node, Express, Mongodb). I've tried running the provided sample, as well as digging out a later version from github but so far no joy.

The Zza version provided from the page http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza (follow the link "Download the Sample") is non-functional. At first, it fails with an error indicating that express no longer has a configure() method and after fixing that, it then struggles with invalid middleware requests like express.favicon().

This is due to the instructions (and the package.json) now causing Express 4.x to be installed instead of Express 3.x since the build requests the latest version by default.

I wonder if the link ought to be updated to point instead to a Zip derived from github, where the package.json explicitly pins the Express version to 3.x ... https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/tree/90c2bbb4b0722c3bb99931940f809844f9c87042/Samples_Unpublished/Zza/Zza.ExpressServer

Anyone know how I should get a working version of the sample app?

For Debian Wheezy, with access to Jessie packages I did the following to install and configure the sample from the Zza.ExpressServer folder provided in github, but I still have a problem, with the server, once launched, reporting "Cannot get /". Still it's progress compared to no server launching at all.

Install nodejs nodejs-legacy, npm and mongodb (I do this by having apt-pinned jessie repositories), but there's many ways to do it. Go to a suitable working directory and put Zza.ExpressServer there...

```
cd Zza.ExpressServer
npm install
npm install mongodb # this seems to have been forgotten in the new package.json
sudo service mongodb stop
sudo unzip data/ZzaMongoDb.zip -d /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:nogroup /var/lib/mongodb/zza.*
sudo service mongodb start
node server
```

Comment: It looks like quite a bit of the application is functioning, given that http://localhost:3000/breeze/zza/Products gives a JSON report of all the products in the Mongodb database successfully. There must be some kind of issue with the routing of '/', for example a module which should be capturing it, but is silently failing because of the assumption it would be routed somewhere in the express architecture, and actually isn't.

Comment: I have managed to get a version of the sample code working, but through a fairly tortuous route. I checked out https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples ran 'npm install' to bring in the relevant dependencies, extracted the zipped zza database into /var/lib/mongodb changed ownership of the files to mongodb:nogroup, then I changed directory in the console to the client folder, and from there I ran node ../server/server.js